# Cordova commend line errors

Tags: cordova

I am trying to setup cordova so I could build apps using html , css and javascript .
Android_home is not set and I have NO idea how to set it thanks you , it comes out this error when I send command `cordova run`.

Running command: `/Users/Master/caolan/platforms/android/cordova/run`

```
ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path: /Users/Master/Desktop/sdk
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/Master/caolan/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Thank you for all help.